# Label se movendo como letreiro digital

Tags: ios, swift, label

Olá, gostaria de saber como que faço em Swift uma frase ficar passando da direita pra esquerda e quando toda frase passar ela ficar fazendo o mesmo procedimento eternamente, como um letreiro digital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar esse efeito da label se movendo *([chamado efeito Marquee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element))* você pode usar essa biblioteca: https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift

Se estiver usando [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) é só adicionar `pod 'MarqueeLabel-Swift'` no seu podfile, ou caso queira adicionar manualmente é só colocar a classe [MarqueeLabel.swift](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift/blob/master/Classes/MarqueeLabel.swift) para dentro do seu projeto.

Agora basta criar uma label no no seu storyboard e colocar a classe dela como custom do tipo MarqueeLabel e conectar com seu @IBOutlet:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var marqueeLabel: MarqueeLabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    marqueeLabel.type = .Continuous
    marqueeLabel.scrollDuration = 5.0
    marqueeLabel.animationCurve = .EaseInOut
    marqueeLabel.fadeLength = 10.0
    marqueeLabel.leadingBuffer = 30.0
    marqueeLabel.trailingBuffer = 20.0
  }
```